# Azure DevOps Pipeline Issue w/ Git Push Tag Operaation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am developing my first Azure DevOps pipeline and I have worked my way through the stages of my pipeline yaml file except for one and I am stuck on it.

It is the application repository tag push operation with Git. I'm getting the following error when I get to that stage --

*You need the Git 'GenericContribute' permission to perform this action. Details: identity 'Build\05fa7f18-2bf1-4a2a-a8a5-36c05ae3c315', scope 'repository'*

I followed the documentation describing how to give the Build Service Account contribute permissions but my pipeline stage still isn't working. I can push the tag from the command line without any problems.

[image: Build Service Security]

This is the last issue that I have and then I can start using this pipeline for deployments.

Comment: Are you sure you're applying the permission to the correct identity?

Comment: Yes I am - our repositories are uniquely named and very descriptive for just this reason.

Comment: I didn't say *repository*, I said *identity*. i.e. `Build\05fa7f18-2bf1-4a2a-a8a5-36c05ae3c315`. Are you sure that identity is the one to which you assigned the `GenericContribute` permission?

Comment: I'm guessing the pipeline runs with collection scope instead of project scope and thus it needs to either be reconfigured to the project scope or the permission must be assigned to the project collloection build service account.